# UWP application doesn't crash when an exception is thrown. Why?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

For once I have the reverse problem my UWP application **doesn't** crash when an exception is thrown.

I have created a simple app from the blank app template and I have implemented an MVVM architecture where I hold the ViewModels in a PCL. This is where I throw my exception.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IDataService dataService;
    private IWebClientService webClientService;

    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService, IWebClientService webClientService)
    {
        this.dataService = dataService;
        this.webClientService = webClientService;

        InitializeAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that even though I can see the exception logged in the output window. The application doesn't crash. Why is that?? I don't do any exception handling that could be suppressing the exception.

Comment: Exceptions on the main thread are reported through the Application.UnhandledException event.

Comment: It will crash eventually, when the task returned by InitializeAsync is garbage collected (unless you mark the exception as handled in Application.UnhandledException)

Comment: @HansPassant I have not implemented a handler for this event in app.xaml.cs. When I changed the signature of the method to `async void` from `async Task` the exception crashes the app as it should. This is in tune with what @ThomasLevesque said. Please make it into an answer and I will accept it.